# Unity3D Camera Constantly moving

Tags: c#, camera, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my own first person camera controls in unity that use both thumbsticks on a joypad. I have this working fine. However, when I move the right thumb stick (the one uses to look left / right & up / down the camera begins to constantly update.

Here is my joypad movement code:

```
  // Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    float speed = transform.localEulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis("LeftRight") * sensitivityX;

    rotationY += Input.GetAxis("UpDown") * sensitivityY;
    rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, speed, 0);

}
```

To control the left thumb stick, I've simply attached the my script to a first person character controller Unity provide.

I know my code is updating every frame, but I assumed that it would only update as and when I press the right thumb stick. If that isn't the case, is there a way I can limit it to only increment when I move the right thumb stick?

Answer (score 1):

The code in Update() will indeed be executed every frame.

The movement you were noticing was mainly due to `transform.localEulerAngles` being called every frame.
The speed parameter was never zero, because you base it on `transform.localEulerAngles.y`

You could just check if the axis value is not zero, like this:

```
void Update()
{

    float inputValueLeftRight = Input.GetAxis("LeftRight");
    if(inputValueLeftRight > 0 || inputValueLeftRight < 0)
    {
       float speed = transform.localEulerAngles.y + inputValueLeftRight * sensitivityX;    
       transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, speed, 0);
    }

    float inputValueUpDown = Input.GetAxis("UpDown");
    if(inputValueUpDown > 0 || inputValueUpDown < 0)
    {
       rotationY += inputValueUpDown * sensitivityY;
       rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);
    }

}
```

Comment: Keep in mind i have no idea if checking for exact zero on the input values is feasible. you might have to leave a little bit of a gap, but there is no way for me to determine how big that gap should be. try experimenting with it.